# Conjugacy class of semisimple elements

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex simple Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and $G_1$ be a complex simple subgroup of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g_1$. We may assume $G$ and $G_1$ to be of adjoint type. Suppose $H_1,H_2 \in \mathfrak g_1$ are two semisimple elements such that $ \ \exists \ \alpha \in G $ such that $\ \alpha H_1 \alpha^{-1}=H_2$. Does there exist $ \  \ \beta \in G_1 $ such that $\ \beta H_1 \beta^{-1}=H_2$?

This is not true if we assume $G_1$ to be a real subgroup.

Comment: The formulation is somewhat out of focus, since the notion of "semisimple" element isn't usually intrinsic for Lie groups.    However, semisimple Lie groups over $\mathbb{C}$ turn out to be the same as semisimple algebraic groups, and the Jordan decomposition of elements is defined intrinsically in the latter.    Anyway, I suspect the answer to your question is "no".   And there's no need to assume the groups are centerless.

Answer (score 1):

In the direction of a positive answer to your question, there are some rather restrictive hypotheses which would suffice, though I'm still not optimistic about getting a positive answer in your very general situation.   Note that $G = \mathrm{GL}(V)$ might as well be a general linear group (or other reductive group), since the center doesn't affect conjugation or the adjoint action on the Lie algebra.

If $G_1$ is embedded in a general linear group $G$ by an irreducible representation (say of algebraic groups), then you can appeal to known results to conclude that conjugacy (= similarity) of two semisimple elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_1$ under $G$ for *all* such representations implies conjugacy under the adjoint action of $G_1$ on $\mathfrak{g}_1$.    But having to consider all irreducible representations of $G_1$ gets outside your framework even if you start with a nice embedding.

For Lie algebras this is a characteristic 0 theorem, proved by M. Gauger [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=-693200333&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&md5=aa8535f59c6e0d45b0a36dadd3215565&searchtype=a).    Soon afterward, Steinberg streamlined the argument and also obtained a close analogue for the groups with less restriction on the characteristic [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=-693203033&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&md5=a6d371a8a22336044bc90d91b27d52d5&searchtype=a).

In any case, the algebraic group setting of these papers is the most natural one for dealing with semisimple elements of the groups or Lie algebras.